# How to use 1 JFrame for all the classes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Good day. I would like to ask how can I use this 1 class that contain the details of my main frame to be used as the frame of all class that I will make? I want this to be the frame of all my classes. Thank you in advance.

```
package ThinkNotOfficial;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame{

    // Global Variables
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Base Frame (global)");
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("Logo.png");

    MainFrame(){
        mainFrame.setSize(720, 720);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create multiple `JPanels` and place them all in your one `JFrame`.  You can create subordinate `JPanels` that make up parts of a main `JPanel`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should create properties class. And each other class for JFrame window

```
public class FrameProperties {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Base Frame (global)");
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("Logo.png");

    public void Properties(){
        mainFrame.setSize(720, 720);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

And then you can create your Frame classes and add your method to it

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    // Global Variables


   MainFrame(){
       FrameProperties frameProperties = new FrameProperties();
       frameProperties.Properties();

    }
```

```
public class SecondFrame extends JFrame {

   SecondFrame(){
       FrameProperties frameProperties = new FrameProperties();
       frameProperties.Properties();

    }
}
```

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
        new SecondFrame();
    }
```

Comment: 1) `MainFrame extends JFrame` do not extend windows or components without good cause. 2) `SecondFrame extends JFrame` Each application should have exactly one frame, just as the OP is intending.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do I add something on a specific class (like on the "MainFrame") like buttons, etc?